# Flying from Niagara Falls to NYC & from NYC to Brussels with a Canadian Visa

Tags: visas, usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, belgian-citizens

I'm finishing up my 3-month internship in Montreal, Canada. Before I go home, I wanted to see Toronto and New York City; here's my plan:

- Leave from Montreal to Toronto (by train)
- Spend 3 Days in Toronto
- Go from Toronto to Niagara Falls (by train)
- From Niagara Falls go to New York City ***(By Plane)***
- Spend 3-4 Days in NYC
- Fly from NYC to Brussels

I'm a Belgian citizen with a Working Holiday Visa for Canada. Is this possible with the current visa I have, or do I need to apply to a special program? And if this is not possible, what are my other options?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You need an ESTA

Comment: @Karlson: He actually doesn't, but it might be a good idea anyway.  See my answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah.  You're right.  He's crossing by land.

Comment: Just a hint: You'll probably want to fly to New York from Buffalo, NY, which is just across the border from the falls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Canadian visa has nothing to do with entering the US.  Canada doesn't really care where you go when you leave, and as far as I know, the US doesn't give any special entry privileges to Canadian visa holders.

As a Belgian citizen, you can enter the US under the [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) for tourism or business up to 90 days; your proposed itinerary certainly qualifies.

It is not necessary to do anything in advance.  However, if you apply for an [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/), it may reduce the amount of paperwork you have to do at the US border.  From https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e1s1#MOST:

> **Do I need to apply for ESTA if... I am a citizen of a VWP country and am visiting the U.S. from Canada or Mexico?**
>
> If you are a citizen of a country that participates in the Visa Waiver Program (VWP), and you enter the U.S. by land from Mexico or Canada, ESTA is not required. If you do not have ESTA, you will be required to complete the paper I-94W form and proceed through a manual entry process at the land border crossing. If you have an approved ESTA when entering the U.S. at a land border crossing, you will not be required to complete the paper I-94W form and your entry process is expedited. However, if issued, you should return your green I-94W card upon departure from the U.S. If you are arriving by air or sea, you do need to apply for ESTA.

Comment: Alright, that helps. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You **do** need an ESTA if you are arriving in the US by plane. The OP doesn't say whether he is flying from Niagara Falls, NY or Niagara Falls ON. In the latter case he would need an ESTA.

Comment: OK, checked, and there are no scheduled flights from NF-ON to NYC, but I'll leave the comment anyway.

Comment: @DJClayworth: By "NF-ON" you mean [YCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Catharines/Niagara_District_Airport)?  According to Wikipedia it has no scheduled passenger service at all.